# HighStock: Range Selector is not hidden on export

Tags: highcharts

I have configured exporting option for Highstock with following settings,

```
exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        filename: 'most-chart',
        chartOptions: {
          title: {},
          subtitle: {},
          rangeSelector:{enabled: false}
        }
    },
```

But still Rangeselector is coming on export.

Comment: This code works for me - the exported image does not include range selector http://jsfiddle.net/23ey3tn0/ How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: @morganfree I tried ur fiddle... rangeselector is still coming for me.

Comment: <script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script> can you try adding offline-exporting module otherwise?

Comment: I added and it did not change anything. What OS/browser do you use? Do you use Highchart server or do you set up your own server?

Comment: Mac OS/Chrome 55V..... offline-exporting will render locally I guess

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. It looks like a bug, so I suggest reporting it on Highcharts github - [link here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues) - and describing all the details.

Comment: Thanks @morganfree .. I will raise an issue